# How to remove the first paragraph just before the first table in google doc using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My google doc looks like this

"Start of Doc"

1st paragraph, that is empty

Table

Last paragraph
"End of Doc"

How can I remove the 1st paragraph just before that table?

I tried the following script

```
function learningdoc(){
var docFileId = "ID_Here";
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFileId);
var body = doc.getBody()
var firstChild = body.getChild(0)
    if (firstChild.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
    Logger.log(firstChild.getType())
    firstChild.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

which doesn't work

I tried the script on another situation like this

"Start of Doc"

1st Empty Paragraph

2nd Empty Paragraph

Table

Last Paragraph

"End of Doc"

This time the script works well. It CAN delete an empty paragraph.

The result i want is

"Start of Doc"

Table

Last Paragraph

"End of Doc"
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of removing the paragraph just before the table.  This assumes there is only 1 table in the document.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let table = body.getTables()[0];
    let previous = table.getPreviousSibling();
    body.removeChild(previous);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Body.getTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getTables())
- [Table.getPreviousSibling()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getPreviousSibling())
- [Body.removeChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removeChild(Element))